# I think there is a mistake between document and source

Tags: cnosdb

When I search the cache config from the document, there is a field named max_immutable_number.

But when I search the source file.

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct CacheConfig {
    #[serde(with = "bytes_num", default = "CacheConfig::default_max_buffer_size")]
    pub max_buffer_size: u64,
    #[serde(default = "CacheConfig::default_partitions")]
    pub partition: usize,
}
```

you can see that there is a partition but not a max_immutable_number. So I think there is a mistake in the document.